# IE6 alerting an array does not show anything

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

First of all, the full code is at work so I'm reciting from memory.

There is a js file with containing an object defined like this:

```
function SomeObject(someArg) {
 this.someMember = someVar.split(".");

 ...
 this.someFunc = function() {
  return this.someMember;
 }
 ...
}
```

There is another js file which uses this object and has a function that looks something like this:

```
someOtherFunc(SomeObject):
   var someOtherVar = SomeObject.someFunc();
   var length = someOtherVar.length;
   ....
```

Now when I add an alert(SomeObject.someFunc()) at the beginning of someOtherFunc all I see is an empty box. However, when I alert SomeObject.someFunc().length I get 1 (because the array has one element). Yet, I have a "length is an undefined..." where var length is defined. Also, when I alert SomeObject.someFunc()[0] I have the value of the element shown (it's a string).

I know it's IE6 (don't ask) and I couldn't provide much context, but I'm still hoping this issue is somewhat known or has some explanation or a workaround.

Comment: @claustrofob, I know. someArg is not in use at relevant areas of the codes, I just added it because the constructor receives an argument.

Comment: If you *really* can't avoid IE6, I suggest using [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) to do your debugging rather than `alert()`. Debugging code in IE6 is a massive pain, made worse by trying to use `alert()` to do it. Firebug Lite at least makes it a bit easier.